# Matlab | Matrix Function of Several Variables

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

I'm working on Matlab and I need to define a matrix function that depends on several variables.

For example, I have this vectors:

```
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

That can contain any real numbers or have any length (same length for t and y, I called it NumData).

I have a function that depends on some parameters P1, P2,...,P5.  What I want to do is to form a Matrix (NumData x 5) that depends of p, a vector of parameters:

I don't know how to step further. I thought of define a Matrix:

```
Matrix = ones(NumData,NumParameters)
```

But when I try to assign, for example

```
Matrix(1,3) = p(1)+3*p(2)
```

I got an error.

I tried to define:

```
Matrix(1,3)=@(p) p(1)+3*p(2)
```

But it's useless...

I tried to define the matrix in code, like this:

```
J=@(p) [1 1 1 exp(-p(5)) -p(4)*exp(-p(5))
1 2 4 exp(-2*p(5)) -p(4)*exp(-2*p(5))
1 3 9 exp(-3*p(5)) -p(4)*exp(-3*p(5))
1 4 16 exp(-4*p(5)) -p(4)*exp(-4*p(5))
1 5 25 exp(-5*p(5)) -p(4)*exp(-5*p(5))]
```

but it isn't good because this is for a specific case...

My main goal is to form J from t vector, and that J depends on the vector parameter p so I can evaluate later

```
A= J(1,2,1,2,2)
```

for example, and then factorize A as QR.

Do you have any suggestions? Or I am asking too much for Matlab?

Comment: Please post the error messages you recieved.

Comment: Your question is very unclear without error messages pasted in. If the error is just somethig along the lines of "indicies out of bounds", then your matrix is not big enought to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, but let me give you some examples of things that will work, in the hopes that it can help you a bit.

```
p=[1 2 3 4 5];
M=zeros(3,2);
M=[p(1) p(2) p(5); p(3)/p(2) p(5)^p(2) exp(p(3))]
```